# Column lines are not in sync in a Kendo grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo grid with too many columns. Initially I chose to hide some columns, but later I decided to display all the columns with a horizontal scrollbar.

I did this by assigning a width to each column. When I did so, the lines between each column are not in sync with the header lines.

I mean, the lines in the data part of the grid, are moved slightly to the left with respect to the header lines.

To clarify, when I give the width for each column in pixels the above problem persists. But, when I give the width in %, the scrollbar is not displayed.

I want to display the scrollbar to show all the columns.

Any ideas about how to do this?

Comment: Please give me some idea. If i am not clear, please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is quite straight forward grid with horizontal scrollbar (ignore the virtualization) http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/virtualization-remote-data.html. 
Have a width on your grid or it's parent and width for each column with their sum over the actual grid width then you get your scrollbar:

```
    { field: "OrderID", title: "Order ID", width: 60 },
```

(I did quite few Kendo grids in the past and never experienced such issue. Sounds like you setting up the column width directly on the html, I can't see how else would Kendo get out off sync.)

Comment: I have a similar issue except I don't want to use a scrollbar which doesn't while solving the sync issues it leaves a vertical scrollbar which isn't used/needed not to mention it's a horizontal sync issue.  I've set the parent width which changes the main grid box but doesn't affect the internal data that continues to expand out, I'd prefer if I could just get the data to go onto a 2nd line like it does in another grid of mine (I checked and I couldn't see any difference between the 2 grids setting so...)

Comment: Nm I figured out why, because I'd typed out a constant line of text with no spaces ie7/8 couldn't handle this and instead kept the text on a single line.

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17543306/kendo-grid-column-width-scrollable might help.

Comment: @Bobby_D_ Actually, your idea was rite. But then, i was using the same thing. Even then i faced the problem of non-sync. Then i found that, it was due to version of IE. I was using IE8. But, the same approach in IE9 was perfect. Anyway, thanks.