# Kendo Grid Column Width + Scrollable

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm trying to bind to a scrollable kendo grid from javascript and having a few issues with column widths.  This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mnTGm/1/) demonstrates the issue (code at the end of the question).  I'm specifying the headers in the html and adding a width to one of the headers.  The javascript then sets the dataSource (in production code this is done via an ajax call).

I want to avoid having to set the columns.width property in the javascript because

- I have many grids that, since my viewmodels are carefully constructed are able to automatically discern the columns required.  We have over 100 girds in our app and having to specify the column list for all of them would be unwieldy.
- It feels wrong anyway, this is styling information.

I do understand that the functionality is due to kendo creating two grids, one for the headers and one for the scrolling content.  However, other control libs I have used in the past that do similar things have always copied the styling information between the two grids in order to facilitate declarative styling while keeping the two tables in sync - I'm just not sure what the "kendo" way for this is.

HTML from fiddle

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th class="p20" data-field="status">Status</th>
        <th data-field="description">Description</th>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Javascript

```
$('table').kendoGrid({
    dataSource: [
        { status: 'On', description: 'a longer description' },
        { status: 'On', description: 'a longer description' },
        { status: 'On', description: 'a longer description' },
        { status: 'On', description: 'a longer description' },
        { status: 'On', description: 'a longer description' },
        { status: 'On', description: 'a longer description' }
    ],
    scrollable: true
});
```

CSS

```
.k-grid-content {
    height: 100px;
}
.p20 {
    width: 20%;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is quite straight forward grid with horizontal scrollbar (ignore the virtualization) http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/virtualization-remote-data.html. Have a width on your grid or it's parent and width for each column with their sum over the actual grid width then you get your scrollbar:

```
{ field: "OrderID", title: "Order ID", width: 60 },
```

Already answer yesterday in your other post :
[Column lines are not in sync in a Kendo grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17523124/column-lines-are-not-in-sync-in-a-kendo-grid)

Or

http://jsfiddle.net/vojtiik/2ApvC/3/

Note I am using bit newer version of kendo and jQuery then you do.

Comment: Absolutely, this would work, but I want to specify my widths in mark-up not in the javascript.  Having to specify every column's details for every grid is far to onerous a task and it's the wrong place (semantically speaking) to be specifying styling.

Comment: Yes, I have realized later on what are you on about, bit different from yesterdays question. How are you planning to deal with grid where the text/value width is more than your 20% ? Do you always display the same data in your columns. You could set width on all of your columns and headers as you wish and deploy ellipsis ("my incomplete value...") to avoid the width/sync difference.

Comment: Basically, kendo sets the table layout to 'fixed' for scrollable grids (which is annoying to start with) with means that some of our columns are much too wide.  We have a few columns which are just status indicator icons and I want to set them to only be a few pixels wide.

Everything else get's ellipsis and the grid is also set to be resizable and horizontal scrollbars appear if necessary (see the grid on the azure management portal for an example of the kind of functionality).  It's suck a shame that kendo takes the "two grids" approach without making the complexity invisible to consumers

Comment: Have a look at my last edit, you could achieve what you are after by using custom attribute on header and the column. It also resolves your semantically concern.

Comment: Thanks @Bobby_D_ , I'll mark this as the accepted answer so far.  I'd still rather have a solution that doesn't involve me creating a columns array in the javascript for every grid that needs one column to have a specific size but this may be the best we have.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `<colgroup/>` and `<col/>` elements with style/class properties.